# What is the meanging of "\expandafter\PDR@getfileinfo\reserved@a\relax? ? \relax\relax"

Tags: document-classes

Needing help of explainning the meaning of the following code for me, the code is in the file "PostDocRep.cls"
that begins with

```
    \NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}[1995/12/01]
    \ProvidesClass{PostDocRep}
      [2009/09/23 v0.1e PostDocRep
       document class]
    ........
    
    \def\PDR@getfileinfo#1 #2 #3\relax#4\relax{%
      \def\PDRfiledate{#1}%
      \def\PDRfileversion{#2}%
      \def\PDRfileinfo{#3}}%
    \expandafter\ifx\csname ver@PostDocRep.cls\endcsname\relax
      \edef\reserved@a{\csname ver@ctextemp_PostDocRep.cls\endcsname}
    \else
      \edef\reserved@a{\csname ver@PostDocRep.cls\endcsname}
    \fi
    \expandafter\PDR@getfileinfo\reserved@a\relax? ? \relax\relax
```

I do not know what is the result of statement

```
\expandafter\ifx\csname ver@PostDocRep.cls\endcsname\relax
```

if it ture or false and which branch it selects?

```
\edef\reserved@a{\csname ver@ctextemp_PostDocRep.cls\endcsname}
```

or

```
  \edef\reserved@a{\csname ver@PostDocRep.cls\endcsname}
```

Moreover, I have no idea of how the statement

```
\expandafter\PDR@getfileinfo\reserved@a\relax? ? \relax\relax
```

execute? why there are so many \relax,

Comment: this is the third question you have asked where you just pick one line out of context and ask what it means. I'm not sure it's a useful way to learn latex.

Comment: the code depends on `ver@ctextemp_PostDocRep.cls`  which is presumably defined somewhere in code you have not shown.

Comment: `\expandafter\ifx\csname ver@PostDocRep.cls\endcsname\relax` should never be true as it follows `\ProvidesClass{PostDocRep}` that defines that command so it is hard to guess why this test is there without seeing the full context

Comment: Why are you using a decade old document class that someone gave you but you don't understand?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle  can I upload the wholefile, and the name of the whole class file is PostDocRep.cls the begins with 
 \NeedsTeXFormat{LaTeX2e}[1995/12/01]
    \ProvidesClass{PostDocRep}
      [2009/09/23 v0.1e PostDocRep
       document class]
    ........ meanwhile, there is no ver@ctextemp_PostDocRep.cls at all, only the file  PostDocRep.cls

Comment: well as I say that branch chould never be used as the test is pointless the command will always be defined in latex.  the code probably predates latex. But anyway I already posted an answer.

Comment: If you really want to learn LaTeX programming refer to [package writing - Where do I start LaTeX programming? - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/12668/where-do-i-start-latex-programming/). Otherwise, I think asking people to do work for you every time is not going to be very well-received

Answer (score 5):

`\reserved@a` will be `2009/09/23 v0.1e PostDocRep document class`

so `\expandafter\PDR@getfileinfo\reserved@a\relax`

is

```
\PDR@getfileinfo 2009/09/23 v0.1e PostDocRep document class\relax
```

which will do

```
  \def\PDRfiledate{2009/09/23}%
  \def\PDRfileversion{v0.1e}%
  \def\PDRfileinfo{PostDocRep document class}%
```

The trailing ? and `\relax` ensure that even if for some reason `\reserved@a` did not have the right form there would still be some space characters and `\relax` so that `\PDR@getfileinfo`  will always see the arguments and not have a runaway argument error looking for a string delimited by a missing `\relax`